# How to get MAC addresses in C# .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, networking, mac-address

**How can I achieve this:**

**1. step:** I would like to get the Ethernet ("RJ45") MAC Address,

**2. step:** if there is no existing one, get the WiFi's MAC Address

**Important:**

- I'm not interested if the adapter is active or not.
- also want to exclude WMVare, VPN or other adapters MAC addresses.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck? This is not a place where you tell us what you want and we do it for you. It's a place where you explain what you have done based on your own research and what happened that you didn't expect when you did it.

Comment: I've removed the VB.NET and C# tags because a question cannot be specific to both languages. If your question relates to a language, specify which it is.

Comment: Do you mean .Net *core* 2.0, or .Net *framework* 2.0? There is a fairly huge difference.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Util now I have the BIOS information, but the problem is, that the BIOS serial number, sometimes returns "Default string", so I would like add another information to generate an unique PC id for licensing purpose. I'm coding in .NET 2.0 C# .

Comment: @JonasH I'm coding on .NET Framework 2.0 in C#. I know that is a very old framework, but I'm stuck on this framework, because I'm using Crystal Reports from VS 2005 and I'm afraid that, if I upgrade, the Crystal Reports would not work any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=net-7.0) to list all network adapters. You can then use the [NetworkInterfaceType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype?view=net-7.0#system-net-networkinformation-networkinterface-networkinterfacetype) and/or name and description to filter and order adapters. Use `.GetPhysicalAddress()` to get the MAC address.

If this is for a license system I would suggest listing all valid adapters for whoever grants the license to chose from. A network adapter may be movable between systems, and that may or may not be desirable.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "listing all valid adapters for whoever grants the license to chose from"? Should I get all MAC addresses and "combine" them to get an unique value?

Comment: @HelloWorld If the customer has two adapters: "Crappy USB Ethernet" and "Intel i210", you might want to generate a license for the later, since there is less chance of it being removed. But there is no good way to select this automatically, so you probably need a human in the loop. You might not want this human to be the customer, since he could easily create a "dongle" this way, and that might not be what you want.

Comment: @HelloWorld You could combine addresses, but if either breaks the license will be invalid.

Comment: so, there no way to detect that the user is using an "USB Enthernet" or not from C#?

Comment: @HelloWorld The interface used to talk to the network adapter is not related to it being removable or not. You can have motherboards with built in USB ethernet, or easily removable PCIe adapters. So even if it was possible it would not guarantee anything.